# Trouble migrating a MySQL database to MS SQL 2012 using the migration assistant

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to migrate a MySQL server database to Microsoft SQL Server 2012. I converted the schema and synchronized the databases, but when I try to do the migration, it doesn't work and I get this when it's done:
[image]

I don't think it even tried to migrate anything. I have no idea what I could have missed. Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess - since the "To" column contains nothing, perhaps the migration has not been configured to move the tables indicated in the report.  If you scroll down, are there any rows that report success?  If you click "Save Report" and view it, does it contain any further details?

Comment: Nothing gets moved and the report pretty much looks like the image I posted.  Without any helpful error messages, I'm kind of lost as to what could have happened.  I'm going to try removing the target database and going through the whole process again and see if anything different happens.